# SACSegmentation find strange inlier

Tags: point-cloud-library

When I use SACSegmentation to find all the perpendicular planes of the floor normal vector, I always getting strange planes. The images show the input point cloud and SACSegmentation results.[image: Original input point cloud]. [image: Correct ground plane]. [image: Wrong SACSegmentation inlier].

I have played around with the setDistanceThreshold value, and the bigger
number it is the larger strange inlier segment I have. However, I alway get the wrong
planes. I also tried to turn on and off the setOptimizeCoefficients, as well as bring the point cloud closer to origin. I even tried with different reasonable ModelTypes and MethodTypes, such as SACMODEL_NORMAL_PLANE and SACMODEL_NORMAL_PARALLEL_PLANE. However, none of them fix the issue. Could anyone provide some suggestions? Thanks in advance.

```
pcl::VoxelGrid<pcl::PCLPointCloud2> sor;
    sor.setInputCloud (cloudPCL2);
    sor.setLeafSize (0.01, 0.01, 0.01);
    sor.filter (*cloudPCL2_result);

    pcl::fromPCLPointCloud2 (*cloudPCL2_result, *cloud_filtered);

    cerr << "PointCloud after filtering: " << cloud_filtered->width * cloud_filtered->height << " data points." << endl;

    pcl::ModelCoefficients::Ptr coefficients (new pcl::ModelCoefficients());
    pcl::PointIndices::Ptr inliers (new pcl::PointIndices ());

    pcl::SACSegmentation<pcl::PointXYZRGB> seg;
    seg.setOptimizeCoefficients (true);

    seg.setModelType (pcl::SACMODEL_PERPENDICULAR_PLANE);
    seg.setMethodType (pcl::SAC_RANSAC);
    seg.setMaxIterations (2000);
    seg.setDistanceThreshold (0.07);
    seg.setAxis(normal);
    seg.setEpsAngle(pcl::deg2rad(20.0));

    int i = 0, nr_points = (int) cloud_filtered->points.size ();
    while (cloud_filtered->points.size () > 0.2 * nr_points) {
        seg.setInputCloud(cloud_filtered);
        seg.segment(*inliers, *coefficients);
        if (inliers->indices.size() == 0) {
            cerr << "Could not estimate a planar model for the given dataset." << endl;
            break;
        }

        extract.setInputCloud(cloud_filtered);
        extract.setIndices(inliers);
        extract.setNegative(false);
        extract.filter(*cloudOutput);

        stringstream ss;
        ss << "plane_" << i << ".pcd";
        writer.write<pcl::PointXYZRGB>(ss.str(), *cloudOutput, false);

        extract.setNegative(true);
        extract.filter(*cloudTmp);
        cerr << "PointCloud representing the planar component: " <<
cloudTmp->width * cloudTmp->height << " data points." << endl;
        cloud_filtered.swap(cloudTmp);
        i++;
    }
```

I expect the SACSegmentation will only find the ground plane and ignore all the points on the wall, but instead I got these strips of the wall along with the correct ground plane.

Comment: In order to use any normal dependent RANSAC algorithm, your input point cloud has to have pre-computed normals.
Compute normals for your input point cloud and use a point type with normals, e.g. `PointXYZRGBNormal` for RANSAC.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have also tried SACSegmentationFromNormals with normals generated from NormalEstimation. However, I'm still having this issue.

Answer (score 0):

From your code+images, I can see that the first RANSAC returns you the floor, then the wall that is parallel to the floor. What you want is the wall that is perpendicular to the floor! So, the quickest way to get it is remove the parallel restriction there and go with the `pcl::SACMODEL_PLANE` after you got your first ransac result. e.g.

```cpp
...
while (...) {
    ...
    seg.segment(*inliers, *coefficients);
    // RESET THE RANSAC MODEL TYPE
    seg.setModelType (pcl::SACMODEL_PLANE);
```

Following your starting code, you would first get a floor with your current axis restriction, then after removing the restriction, you would be able to get a lot of better result.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. As I mentioned, what I'm trying to achieve is finding all the planes that is perpendicular to the ground plane (horizontal planes), which could be the ground plane or tables, and ignore all the wall (vertical planes). However, the result of my code will find the ground plane first, but also find those strips on the wall (what I expect RANSAC will ignore). Thanks for the help.